# When using System.console() in Java, why do output pipes break?

Tags: java, unix, console, pipe

I'm using System.console().readPassword() to read a password from the terminal and perform a set of actions. This all works fine, however when attempting to pipe the output to grep, head, awk, whatever, it breaks with System.console() returning null.

This code should replicate it:

```
public class TestPiping
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String password = new String(System.console().readPassword("Whats the password?"));
        System.out.println(password);
    }
}
```

And then compiling running it:

```
$ javac -g TestPiping.java
$ java TestPiping         
Whats the password?
hello
$ java TestPiping | head
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestPiping.main(TestPiping.java:5)
```

Why is the redirected stdout affecting stdin? Do I need to manually read the password without using java.io.console?

Comment: can you pass it as an parameter ?

Comment: I've implemented a '--password-file' option, but it'd be cool if the user didn't need to change password techniques just to redirect stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and reading I'm going to close this question. The trouble is that (as @jshelto alluded to) the Console uses a JNI interface to disable text echo in the terminal and do a whole bunch of other low level actions while reading in characters. I decompiled the java.io.console stuff to check it out. This has to be cross platform as well, so it gets a little hairy. I still couldn't identify where the decision is made to return null but it seems to be a security related one. ie: if there is any doubt that the stdin is secure, return null.

A work around I found was to implement a Thread that erases console text using the '\b' char while you're reading input. Although it was a general alternative to Console readPassword(), it broke when stdout was redirected using a unix pipe. It also wasn't very reliable or elegant. See http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA602/Eraserlab/pwdmasking.html for more details.

In the end I've just decided to force the user to use a '--password-file' option when Console() returns null. This is probably how most users will end up using the application anyway, or through a GUI where password entry will be much easier.